# Solving for $x$ using the inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations

I'm having some trouble finding a simplified solution for $x$ in the equation below, where $Y$ and $Z$ are square $n \times n$ matrices with non-zero determinant for $(Y+Z)$, and $w$ is an $n$-dimensional vector:

$$x^{T}(Y + Z) = w^{T}$$

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this problem? I've been stuck on this for a while and feel like I am missing something very simple. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can't just right multiply by $(W+Z)^{-1}$ then take the transpose of both sides?

Comment: @AmaanM You mean right multiply by $(Y+Z)^{-1}$

Comment: Ah so would the final solution look something like $x = w[(Y + Z)^{T}]^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio thanks, that is what I meant

Comment: @Sat0shi_G close, don't forget $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$